# How to implement Cocos2d multitouch sprite rotation?

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, cocos2d-iphone

I have already implemented multitouch image rotation using standard iOS graphics library (Core Graphics).

It looks like this:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ([touches count] == 2) {
        NSArray *twoTouches = [touches allObjects];
        UITouch *first = [twoTouches objectAtIndex:0];
        UITouch *second = [twoTouches objectAtIndex:1];

        CGFloat currentAngle = angleBetweenLinesInRadians([first previousLocationInView:self.view], [second previousLocationInView:self.view], [first locationInView:self.view], [second locationInView:self.view]);

        pic1.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(pic1.transform, currentAngle);

    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to implement this solution in my Cocos2d project. First I registered the CCTouchDispacher in my init method.

```
- (id) init
{
    ...
    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
    ...
}
```

In my ccTouchMoved function I changed (UITouch *) to (NSSet *) and built the project just to be sure everything was correct. As a result I got following warning: "Incompatible Objective-C types initializing 'struct NSSet *', expected 'struct UITouch *'".

As everything still seemed to be working correctly I moved on and tried to extract first and second touch objects from (NSSet *) touch.

```
- (void)ccTouchMoved:(NSSet *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ([touch count] == 2) {
        NSArray *twoTouches = [touch allObjects];
        UITouch *first = [twoTouches objectAtIndex:0];
        UITouch *second = [twoTouches objectAtIndex:1];
    }

}
```

Now I tried to compile it, which worked, but after I triggered ccTouchMoved through iPhone simulator, I got following error message: "-[UITouch count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x542d6a0'".

Can somebody please explain, how to get this Cocos2d ccTouchMoved method to recognize and process multitouch events?

Thanks.

Comment: hi pacman, could you tell me how did you implemented angleBetweenLinesInRadians ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've used wrong CC2D method.

you should use

```
- (BOOL)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

rather then

```
- (void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

as you want to capture multiple touches whereby ccTouchMoved capturs only one

Comment: Hi Tom, sorry for repeated question from above comment, Could you give me idea on how angleBetweenLinesInRadians has been implemented (algorithm) on above pacman's code? Its taking four CGPoint arguments. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for being not specific, can get the angle between two point with atan2, i just wanted to know about those 4 parameters, why previous location in view arguments were used for the calculation ? I am getting current angle with current locations so is something more other stuff being calculated ?

Comment: He's most likely calculating angle between lines creating by moving two fingers touching the screen and he check the angle between location of previous position of two fingers and current position of two fingers this way you can check by what angle user rotated the fingers touching the screen. So the thing you are missing I guess is that you dont want to check the angle between two points but rather angle by which a line in previous check vs current have rotated